# How to make a Callout batch class?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, batch, scheduled-apex

I have a Callout with Lists and Maps. This takes objects from a resource and transfers them to my Lightning Component. How can I create Batch for this? I need Batch to schedule my callouts after every 5 minutes. I'm trying to make refreshable component without page reloading. And schedule is the first and main step.

I need the objects (cards = records) to make reports and dashboards with them if I want (some analytics) and I want to display it on the front end. I'm communicating through Callouts. Now I get my new records after page refreshing.

My Callout:

```
private static HttpResponse getHttpResponse(String apiCall, String operation){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(apiCall + 'MyKeyTokenIsHere');
    request.setMethod(operation); 
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    return response;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getBoards(){
    HttpResponse response = getHttpResponse('MyApiCallIsHere', 'GET');
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    List<Object> boards = (List<Object>) results.get('boards');
    List<String> textBoards = new List<String>();

    for(Object oneBoard : boards){
        String boardInText = String.valueOf(oneBoard);
        textBoards.add(boardInText);
    }
    return textBoards;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, String> getLists(){
    HttpResponse response = getHttpResponse('MyApiCallIsHere', 'GET');
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    List<Object> lists = (List<Object>) results.get('lists');
    Map<String, String> createdListsMap = new Map<String, String>();

    for(Object oneList : lists){
        String listInText = String.valueOf(oneList);
        //And maybe I can get these values more professionally? 'substringBetween' is good, but...
        String listName = listInText.substringBetween('name=', '}');
        String listId = listInText.substringBetween('id=', ',');
        createdListsMap.put(listId, listName);
    }
    createTasks();
    return createdListsMap;
}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Object__c> getCards(){
        List<Object__c> taskObjects = [SELECT Id, ListId__c, Name FROM Object__c WHERE ListId__c != ''];
        return taskObjects;
    }

    public static void createTasks(){   
        HttpResponse response = getHttpResponse('MyApiCallIsHere', 'GET');
        Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        List<Object> receivedCards = (List<Object>) results.get('cards');
        List<Object__c> newCardsList = new List<Object__c>();

        for(Object eachCard : receivedCards){
            String cardInText = String.valueOf(eachCard);
            String name = cardInText.substringBetween('), name=', '}');
            String listId = cardInText.substringBetween('), listId=', ',');

            Object__c newCard = new Object__c(
                Name = name,
                ListId__c = listId
            );
            newCardsList.add(newCard);
        } 
        try {
            upsert newCardsList CardId__c;
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Lightning cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="MyCallout" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name='objects' type='Object__c[]'/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<div class="slds-scrollable" style="width:100%">
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="false">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.columns}" var="column" indexVar="key">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="4"> 
                <lightning:card>
                    <aura:set attribute="title">
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" >
                            <div class="slds-col slds-scrollable">{!column.value}</div>
                        </div>
                    </aura:set>
                </lightning:card>
                <lightning:card>
                    <div class="slds-scrollable">
                        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.objects}" var="obj">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!column.key == obj.ListId__c}">
                                    <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                                        <div onclick="{!c.openCard}" data-row="{!obj.Name}">
                                            <lightning:card>
                                                <aura:set attribute="title">
                                                    <div>{!obj.Name}</div> 
                                                </aura:set>
                                            </lightning:card>
                                        </div>
                                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                                </aura:if>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:layout> 
                    </div>
                </lightning:card>   
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
</div>
```

Lightning controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
//still without boards
    helper.lists(component, event, helper);
    helper.cards(component, event, helper);
}
```

Lightning helper:

```
lists : function(component, event, helper) {
    let getLists = component.get("c.getLists");

    getLists.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {                
            let arrayMapKeys = [];
            let result = response.getReturnValue();
            for(let key in result){
                arrayMapKeys.push({key:key, value:result[key]});
            }
            component.set('v.columns', arrayMapKeys);
        }
    });           
    $A.enqueueAction(getLists);
},

cards : function(component, event, helper) {
    let getCards = component.get("c.getCards");

    getCards.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            let myAcc=response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.objects", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });           
    $A.enqueueAction(getCards);
},
```

The problem is that the standard Batch execute method looks like this:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> records) {         
    String endpoint;        

    for ( integer i = 0; i< records.size(); i++ ){
        try {                  
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            Http http = new Http();

            endpoint = 'Your endpoint';

            req.setHeader('Authorization', header);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setBody('Information you wanna send');
            req.setCompressed(true);

            if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {      
                res = http.send(req);
                String sJson = res.getBody();
                System.debug('Str:' + res.getBody());
            }             
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            System.debug('Error:' + e.getMessage() + 'LN:' + e.getLineNumber() );           
        }
    }
}
```

But how to use it for `GET` with a few Lists and Maps?

Comment: Why do you need a batch class? I don't see that you are running any callouts in a loop. You won't be able to return values from a batch class to a Lightning component.

Comment: I need it because of schedule. I need to make callouts every 5 minutes.

Comment: Would you [edit] your question to add more detail about your overall requirements and how you intend to use the data in your Lightning component?

Comment: Thank you. I've just done it. I'm trying to make refreshable component without page reloading. And schedule is the first and main step.

Comment: And why I won't be able to return values from a batch class to a Lightning component? I can do it with another `@AuraEnabled` method to call batch. Or not?

Comment: Batch classes are asynchronous. They don't return results.

Comment: And how can I implement it? And is it even possible to implement this?

Comment: Michael, I still have no idea what your design goal is. You're calling out to somewhere (Trello?) and writing records to the database that you want to show in the Lightning front-end, right? Why do you want to do this every five minutes? You can't do that in Asynchronous Apex without ugly workarounds. Do you need the objects in the database, or do you just want to display them on the front end? How are you communicating to your component that there is new data to load? Again, please [edit] to expand.

Comment: Thank you. Done it.